# How to change AG Grid chart resize behavior?

Tags: vuejs2, ag-grid

I have a Vue 2 application that uses AG Grid.  I am in the process of upgrading from AG Grid version 23.2.0 to version 28.2.1, and am running into trouble with the behavior of the charts.  I have a pie chart with the legend placed to the right of the chart.  In version 23.2.0, if the dialog containing the chart is made smaller, the legend moves closer to the pie chart, as you would expect.  As the legend moves closer to the pie chart, the pie chart shrinks to accommodate the legend.  As the dialog continues to shrink, the legend spills off the edge of the dialog, but is still visible.

In version 28.2.1, if the legend gets too close to the pie chart, the legend just disappears, leaving only the pie chart.  This is not desirable behavior; I'd like the legend to remain visible.  I've played with various options to try to prevent the legend from disappearing, but to no avail.  There's an `autoSize` parameter, which is `true` by default, that controls the size of the pie chart.  I tried setting that to `false`, thinking I could emulate the old behavior programmatically, but with that option off, the legend doesn't appear at all.  Does anyone know how to restore the old behavior, or at least emulate the old behavior programmatically?